# Deriving D'Alembert Formula for Semi-Infinite String

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$c$ is constant, given

$u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}, x > 0 , t >0 \\ u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0, \ for \ all \ x>0 \\
u(0,t)=f(t), t>0 \ f(0)=0$

I am asked to find the D'Alembert Solution for this problem.
This is my attempt:

Let $ \xi = x+ct$ and $\eta = x-ct$.
Then define $\Phi = \Phi(\xi,\eta) = u(x,t),$ where $x = \frac{\xi+\eta}{2}$ and $t = \frac{\xi-\eta}{2c}$.

I expressed the initial problem in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$. (After a bunch of derivation)

$u_{\xi \eta}=0$

After integrating with respect to $\xi$ and $\eta$, I got:

$u(\xi ,\eta)= \alpha(\xi) + \beta(\eta)$.

Then using $u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$,

I obtained $u(x,0)=\alpha(x) + \beta(x) =0$(1)

Using  $u_t(x,0)=0$, I got $c\alpha'(x)-c\beta'(x)=0$, and so

$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=\frac{K}{c}$ (2). Adding (1) and (2) side-by-side, I got
$\alpha(x)=-\beta(x)=\frac{K}{2c}$.

However, I couldn't figure out how to move on. Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: Use the so called "odd extension" of your initial data, that is $u_{\text{ext}}(x,0)=u(x,0)$ for $x\geq 0$ and $u_{\text{ext}}(x,0)=-u(-x,0)$ for $x<0$ and then just use the usual D'Alembert formula.